# onStage instances being unexpectedly null

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, instance, flash-ide

I made a pre-loader for an SWF in the first frame i have following code

```
import flash.events.Event;
stop();
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME , onEnterHandler,false,0,false);
function onEnterHandler(e:Event)
{
    trace(progbar);
    trace(jot);
    trace(spark);
    progbar.width = (this.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded / this.loaderInfo.bytesTotal) * 398;
    jot.x = progbar.x + progbar.width;
    jot.y = progbar.y;
    spark.x = jot.x;
    spark.y = jot.y + 10;
    jot.loadtext.text = String(Math.round(progbar.width / 398 * 100)) + " %";
    if (this.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded == this.loaderInfo.bytesTotal)
    {
        gotoAndStop(2);
    }
```

}

when i run the code it gives the following output in **output window** .Below is just a part of the output

**The thing which is confusig is at first trace statement produces the correct output but after that trace statements start to produce null**

```
[object ProgBar]
[object Jot]
[object Spark]
null
null
null
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at Final_fla::MainTimeline/onEnterHandler()
null
null
null
```

Comment: If progbar, jot and spark aren't in frame 2 your output is normal.

Comment: Could you put the code of your second frame ?

Comment: there is no code in the second frame @akmozo .And one other thing i just declared 3 variables in first frame code as 'var pb = progbar' then used pb in the onEnterHandler then its fine now . idi the same for jot and spark. Now it is working fine

Comment: you don't remove your enterframe listener but you still jump to frame 2 anyway where there's no progbar, jot, spark, etc. But the listener still runs and produce those errors

Comment: @BotMaster you gave the most clear answer